# Hibernate Save many different Objects with one session.save

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 4 Objects and I don't want to use session.save(obj) for every object. Is there a way to save all objects in a loop or at once.

For a loop i will have to increment the variables name, but I think that is not possible or a "good way" to solve the problem.

```
    final Test a1 = new Test(6,"AA", 50, 100000,"20.04.2016","AAA", 111, "2016", "EEE");
    final Test a2 = new Test(7,"AB", 1050, 200000,"20.04.2016","BBB", 333, "2016", "EEE");
    final Test a3 = new Test(8,"AC", 40, 300000,"20.04.2016","CCC", 222, "2016", "UUU", "YY", 5, "SSS");
    final Test a4 = new Test(9,"PD", 400, 400000,"20.04.2016","DDD", 444, "2016", "CCC", "YY", 12, "RRR");

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(a1);
    session.save(a2);
    session.save(a3);
    session.save(a4);

    session.getTransaction().commit()
```

Comment: *"I have 4 Objects and I don't want to use session.save(obj) for every object."* Why not exactly? Providing context can give people an idea what kind of solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use an array

```
Test[] tests = new Test[] {new Test(), new Test()};

for(Test test : tests) {
  session.save(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read about batch processing, it should be useful for you.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html

For example:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```